# is there any solution for "unable to complete previous operation due to low memory" on file select

Tags: php, memory, poco

Hello I have a web app that is developed in php, ajax. Everything is ok on many of users mobile's web browsers but some of user that use `pocof2 pro`, has this issue => on file select everything crashes with this message `"unable to complete pervious operation due to low memory"`

I tried to change the code, even delete everything except input file but getting the same error.

This is my sample code for get image from fileinput

```
function loadFile(event, img) {
    var output = document.getElementById(img);
    output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    $("#"+img).css("display", "block");
    output.onload = function() {
      URL.revokeObjectURL(output.src) // free memory
    };
}
```

Comment: Hello, please read this and revise your code:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Also, the code you have provided is JavaScript, but the question is tagged as PHP.

Comment: Hello, I have the same issue on my webapp on my Samsung S20FE, I can upload 4 or 5 pictures but the next one I get that message. Did you find a solution?